# Creating custom volley error

Tags: android, android-volley

Is it possible to create custom volley error object with custom message and error.

As per documentation VolleyError object can be created but i want to know whats right way to handle custom error based on some error code sent from server

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create custom volley error object with custom message and error.

**YES**

Pass `VolleyError` and `Context` object in this function.

```
public static String getMessage(Object error, Context context) {
 String strError = "";
  if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
      strError = "TimeoutError";
  }
  else if (error instanceof NetworkError) || (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
      strError = "NetworkError";
  }
  else if (error instanceof ServerError) || (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
      strError = "ServerError";
  }
  return strError;
}
```

For more info refer this [link](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/). At the end of it is described **Error Handling** portion.